# Show entity definitions inside title of divs

Tags: html, reactjs, character-set

Having this HTML block in a React app:

```
<div className="my-class" title={myValue}>
   <div>{myValue}</div>
</div>
```

The content of `myValue` is `MyCompany™`.

The inner div is showing the content correctly.

But the title, which appears when hover, replaces ™ with `&trade;` and shows it like this: `MyCompany&trade;`.

Why is this happening for the title? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, which is not ideal, but it is fine. So, the code should look like that:

```
let title = ["MyCompany", <span>™</span>]
<div className="my-class" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: title }}>
   <div>{title }</div>
</div>
```

If your entity is dynamic, like you told me in the comments, then we can do the following trick:

```
const parseASCII = (string) => { 
  const htmlTextArea = document.createElement('textarea'); 
  textarea.innerHTML = string; 
  return htmlTextArea.value; 
}
```

Comment: it would work if we have that format all the time but I used it just for an example. in reality the title can have or not that entity or maybe it could be situated inside the string